# Magento2 Custom module Footer

Tags: magento2, email, overriding

I have Created a Custom Email template module, I wants asign all the footer design same as my module footer design, how to override Default Footer to my custom email module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom header and footer templates for email.

Now navigate to

> Content >> Design >> Configuration >> your_theme >> Other Settings >>
>   Transactional Emails

Select your `custom header and footer email templates` for **Header Template** and **Footer Template**.

You can call these templates using below lines in an email template

For header template:

> {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

For footer template:

> {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

Comment: I am happy to help :)

Comment: My custom design css not effecting to footer css for the custom footer, and when i remove the header template my design is breaking why?